# How to Fix Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded on p-dialog close - Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm running Angular 10. I have an application that has a modal dialog that shows the tabular results of query. When the query results are less than 4005 rows I can close the dialog box without error. Anything above 4005 rows throws the following error:


vendor.js:49066 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

    at Array.push ()

    at _query (vendor.js:1781:20)

    at WebAnimationsDriver.query (vendor.js:7926:14)

    at TransitionAnimationEngine._flushAnimations (vendor.js:5793:25)

    at TransitionAnimationEngine.flush (vendor.js:5695:26)

    at InjectableAnimationEngine.flush (vendor.js:6863:30)

    at vendor.js:125487:25

    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:3967:160)

    at Zone.run (polyfills.js:3693:37)

    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (vendor.js:77577:26)

    at AnimationRendererFactory.end (vendor.js:125484:20)

    at renderComponentOrTemplate (vendor.js:53050:23)

    at tickRootContext (vendor.js:54461:5)

    at detectChangesInRootView (vendor.js:54486:3)

    at RootViewRef.detectChanges (vendor.js:56149:7)

    at ApplicationRef.tick (vendor.js:78932:20)

Here is how I display my dialog:

```
<div *ngIf="showcts">
<p-dialog [(visible)]="displayDrillDown" [modal]="true" [style]="{ width: '90vw' }" header="{{ drilldownTitle }}">
    <app-ct-table-imsid-data [data]="ctdata"></app-ct-table-imsid-data>
    <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
        <p-button (click)="displayDrillDown = false" label="Close" styleClass="p-button-text"></p-button>
    </ng-template>
</p-dialog>
```

The div above contains a dialog that holds another component (the one that generates the tabular data view). The .ts file sets the visible property to "true" and passes the criteria to the component in the dialog.

```
    this.displayDrillDown = true;
    this.ctdata = criteria;
```

Clicking the "Close" button in the dialog (p-button) sets the visible property to false. When the recordset in the dialog is 4005 and below, it closes. Above 4005 it throws the error.

I can fully interact with this child app. It can sort the entire dataset,  export the dataset to Excel, & filter the dataset. The failure ONLY occurs when I click the Close button, or the X in the upper right hand corner of the dialog box.

What can I do to correct this behavior?

Comment: See the docs related to [p-button](https://primeng.org/button#api.button.emitters). It's looks like the event is `(onClick)` instead of `(click)`. BTW the CallStackSize generally is caused by an infinite loop (a loop without increment the variable, a recursive function it's called to shelf, an event that cause a new event is happends and this last execute the first one...)

Comment: Both onClick and  click seem to work interchangeably. As for the "Infinite Loop", I can't see where that is happening, and how to isolate it.